# How to notify webOS that I just saved a photo?

Tags: photo, webos

I'm writing an application that saves photos to a webOS Device.  After my app saves a photo, I've noticed that it doesn't show up in the Palm-supplied Photos app.  What can I do so that the photo can be seen in the Photos app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:
https://developer.palm.com/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=3791

There is currently a bug in webOS that prevents this from working.  As a workaround, calling the download manager twice forces a refresh.